# Unhandled promise rejection on repeat execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose-schema

This is my code:

```
app.post("/blogs/:id/comments", function (req, res) {
    blog.findById(req.params.id, function (err, finded) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(finded)
            console.log(err);
            console.log("finded data")
            res.redirect("/blogs");
        } else {
            Comment.create(req.body.comment, function (err, comment) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(comment)
                    console.log(err);
                    console.log("my coomeent")


                } else {
                    finded.comments.push(comment);
                    finded.save();
                    res.redirect("/blogs/" + finded._id);
                }
            })
        }
    })
});
```

When i am trying to insert comment second time code gives the following error:

> .(node:6064) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): ValidationError: blog validation failed:
>   comments: Cast to [undefined] failed for value
>   "[{"_id":"5a7dee043918a20128a1e39e","text":"hey","author":"himansu","__v":0}]"
>   at path "comments" (node:6064) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
>   promise rejections are depre cated. In the future, promise rejections
>   that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
>   non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 1):

Himansu,I think method `finded.comments.push(comment);` returning a promise. So you have to handle the promise. like:

```
finded.comments.push(comment)
.then(result => {
    finded.save();
    res.redirect("/blogs/" + finded._id);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
})
```